# Еженедельный таймер на Python

Tags: python, время, таймер

Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет считать количество времени до определенного дня, я уже написала скрипт, который это делает, но суть в том, что мне нужно сделать отсчет времени до определенного дня недели, а не даты. Например: "До понедельника осталось 3 дня 2 часа 10 минут 24 секунд". Подскажите пожалуйста метод или библиотеку, которая помогла бы мне помочь в этом.

Comment: Я нашла нечто близкое по смыслу, но так и не смогла переписать это под мою задачу(
`import datetime
delta = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1) - datetime.datetime.now()

print(delta.days, delta.seconds // 3600, (delta.seconds // 60) % 60, delta.seconds % 60)`

Comment: Ответ дал ниже - изучайте, но пишите в дальнейшем в вопросах, что конкретно не получается, раз у ж с примером стали работать. Полезнее будет.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотеку вы уже нашли. Надо было почитать её описание (найти поиском, например, вот, что нашел я: https://all-python.ru/osnovy/modul-datetime.html), а дальше продумать в голове алгоритм, возможно, посчитав на бумажке в конкретных примерах. Затем перенести в код. Пример получившегося кода - ниже.

```
import datetime

target_day = int(input ("введите номер дня недели, начиная с понедельника (ПН - 1, ВС - 7): "))

now = datetime.datetime.now()      # текущие дата и время
day_today = datetime.datetime.isoweekday(now)  # текущий день - его номер

# Сколько ждать осталось
days_to_wait = (target_day - day_today + 6) % 7
hours_to_wait= 24 - now.hour - 1
munutes_to_wait = 60 - now.minute - 1
seconds_to_wait = 60 - now.second - 1

print ("Осталось дней:", days_to_wait, "часов:", hours_to_wait, "минут:", munutes_to_wait, "секунд:", seconds_to_wait)
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)